# fwrite not working when a string was concat from a foreach of DOM Object

Tags: php, dom

Hi can anyone help me why is that when a string was concat in a foreach from inside a DOMDocument Object array the variable wont write using fwrite??

i tried creating an array manually and then when use in a foreach it works and write the contents in the text file but somehow it wont work in a DOMDocument. i also tried making the DomDocument into an array using iterator_into_array but still does not work

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html); 
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a');


foreach($nodes as $node) {
   $content.= "sometext";
} 

//if i var_dump($content) here it displays the output

$filename = "output.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, 'w+');
fwrite($file, $content); //content not writing in the text file
fclose($file);
```

Comment: how about echoing `$content`

Comment: So your problem is that `$nodes` is empty? what happens if you put `print_r($nodes); exit;` on line 5? Do you get an output? If not, something's wrong with your `$doc` (maybe it has no `<a>` tags in it or the DOM is invalid?)

Comment: no its not empty when i print_r or var_dump $nodes it also displays the content , its very really weird why wont the concat text inside foreach wont output in the text file

Comment: @nogad yes i alreadyt echoed and it displays the content